# Android animate layout changed weight height

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, layout

I have two layouts

```
[layout 1]
[layout 2]
```

with equal weight. When I scroll down, I change weight of `[layout 1]` and `[layout 2]`.

I want to know how is it possible to animate layout change weight.
I've tried

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

and

```
LayoutTransition transition = new LayoutTransition();
mapLayout.setLayoutTransition(transition);`
```

but none of this methods works.

Comment: it is a normal property of your layout, so animate it the same way every ObjectAnimator does (see ObjectAnimator docs for more info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this resize animation.

```
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation
{
    int _startWidth;
    int _targetWidth;
    View _view;
    private int _targetHeight;
    private int _startHeight;

    public ResizeAnimation(View view, int targetWidth, int targetHeight)
    {
        _view = view;
        _targetWidth = targetWidth;
        _startWidth = view.getWidth();

        _targetHeight = targetHeight;
        _startHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        setFillAfter(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
    {
        int newWidth = (int) (_startWidth + (_targetWidth - _startWidth) * interpolatedTime);
        int newHeight = (int) (_startHeight + (_targetHeight - _startHeight) * interpolatedTime);

        _view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
        _view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
        _view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {

        private float mStartWeight;
        private float mDeltaWeight;
        private LinearLayout mContent;
        private boolean direction;// true - up; false - down

        public ExpandAnimation(LinearLayout content, float startWeight,
                float endWeight) {
            mStartWeight = startWeight;
            mDeltaWeight = endWeight - startWeight;
            mContent = content;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mContent
                    .getLayoutParams();
            mStartWeight = lp.weight;
            lp.weight = (mStartWeight + (mDeltaWeight * interpolatedTime));
            mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```